# Google Play Store says my app uses AdMob

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, admob, ads

we are the creator of TourisMap. We created our app with **Android Studio** and we published our app 3 days ago and we are so happy! Today we studies what the **Google Play Developer Console** says and we found that!

```
Supported by ads: We found SDK ads in your app. We found some SDK For in one or more active APK:
- Version: 1, SDK: AdMob
- Version: 20151027, SDK: AdMob
If your app running ads, change its statement on "Yes". Failure to complete statement of the presence of ads is considered a violation of the rules and may result in the removal of the app from Google Play. To learn more, visit our Help Center.
```

This message says "*You said your app does not use ads but we found SDK AdMob into your production app! Even into your app version for beta testing!*". Are you serious? We don't know what AdMob is and we do not design our app for ads! We want to delete this situation, we think we have to set something into the code but we don't use any ads/banner sdk, so we don't know where we have to set! How can we manage that?

Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Image is not attached in your question.Click on Your Project Then press F4(`Open Module Setting`) in that check `Ads` option under `Developer services` and check the tickbox.

Comment: Sorry Madhukar: our stackoverflow needs a reputation of 10 to post images :( 

Thanks for your answer: it works like a charm! <3 Can we add your name on our app's "thanks to" view?

Comment: Glad it helped :). Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have included the Google Play Services library **which includes Admob**. Either include only those parts of Google Play Services that you need (it also ships in discrete library blocks for each piece of functionality, or specifically exclude the Admob library.

Comment: Hello William, thanks for your answer, As @Madhukar said, we can use Google Play Services (aka Google Services) without include the ads. How? Well, in Android Studio I (select my project) -> (press F4) -> (the window 'Project Structure' is open) -> Ads -> Uncheck "AdMob - Let's you monetize your app by showing ads tailored to your users" (thank you again @Madhukar).Google is very sensitive about "ads": they send us an email:
"Hello Google Play Developer, [...] By **January 11, 2016**, you must sign in to the Play Developer Console and declare whether your apps contain ads [...]"